# Elasticsearch - Cardinality over Full Field Value

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a document that looks like this:

```
{
   "_id":"some_id_value",
   "_source":{
      "client":{
         "name":"x"
      },
      "project":{
         "name":"x November 2016"
      }
   }
}
```

I am attempting to perform a query that will fetch me the count of unique project names for each client. For this, I am using a query with `cardinality` over the `project.name`. I am sure that there are only `4` unique project names for this particular client. However, when I run my query, I get a count of `5`, which I know is wrong.

The project names all contain the name of the client. For instance, if a client is "X", project names will be "X Testing November 2016", or "X Jan 2016", etc. I don't know if that is a consideration.

This is the mapping for the document type

```
{
   "mappings":{
      "vma_docs":{
         "properties":{
            "client":{
               "properties":{
                  "contact":{
                     "type":"string"
                  },
                  "name":{
                     "type":"string"
                  }
               }
            },
            "project":{
               "properties":{
                  "end_date":{
                     "format":"yyyy-MM-dd",
                     "type":"date"
                  },
                  "project_type":{
                     "type":"string"
                  },
                  "name":{
                     "type":"string"
                  },
                  "project_manager":{
                     "index":"not_analyzed",
                     "type":"string"
                  },
                  "start_date":{
                     "format":"yyyy-MM-dd",
                     "type":"date"
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

This is my search query

```
{
   "fields":[
      "client.name",
      "project.name"
   ],
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "must":{
            "match":{
               "client.name":{
                  "operator":"and",
                  "query":"ABC systems"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "aggs":{
      "num_projects":{
         "cardinality":{
            "field":"project.name"
         }
      }
   },
   "size":5
}
```

These are the results I get (I have only posted 2 results for the sake of brevity). Please find that the num_projects aggregation returns 5, but must only return 4, which are the total number of projects.

```
{
   "hits":{
      "hits":[
         {
            "_score":5.8553367,
            "_type":"vma_docs",
            "_id":"AVTMIM9IBwwoAW3mzgKz",
            "fields":{
               "project.name":[
                  "ABC"
               ],
               "client.name":[
                  "ABC systems Pvt Ltd"
               ]
            },
            "_index":"vma"
         },
         {
            "_score":5.8553367,
            "_type":"vma_docs",
            "_id":"AVTMIM9YBwwoAW3mzgK2",
            "fields":{
               "project.name":[
                  "ABC"
               ],
               "client.name":[
                  "ABC systems Pvt Ltd"
               ]
            },
            "_index":"vma"
         }
      ],
      "total":18,
      "max_score":5.8553367
   },
   "_shards":{
      "successful":5,
      "failed":0,
      "total":5
   },
   "took":4,
   "aggregations":{
      "num_projects":{
         "value":5
      }
   },
   "timed_out":false
}
```

FYI: The project names are `ABC`, `ABC Nov 2016`, `ABC retest November`, `ABC Mobile App`

Comment: Can you provide a gist with your test scenario? (mapping of the index, some data samples and the query)

Comment: @AndreiStefan - I have added the details that you have asked for. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the following mapping for your `project.name` field:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "vma_docs": {
      "properties": {
        "client": {
          "properties": {
            "contact": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "name": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          }
        },
        "project": {
          "properties": {
            "end_date": {
              "format": "yyyy-MM-dd",
              "type": "date"
            },
            "project_type": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "name": {
              "type": "string",
              "fields": {
                "raw": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed"
                }
              }
            },
            "project_manager": {
              "index": "not_analyzed",
              "type": "string"
            },
            "start_date": {
              "format": "yyyy-MM-dd",
              "type": "date"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It's basically a subfield called `raw` where the same value put in `project.name` is put in `project.name.raw` but without touching it (tokenizing or analyzing it). And then the query you need to use is:

```
{
  "fields": [
    "client.name",
    "project.name"
  ],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match": {
          "client.name": {
            "operator": "and",
            "query": "ABC systems"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "num_projects": {
      "cardinality": {
        "field": "project.name.raw"
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 5
}
```