# elasticsearch aggregation - exact count for bucket

Tags: elasticsearch

Elasticsearch newbie question.  I loaded shakespeare.json into Elastic, and I'm trying to figure out how to do an aggregation analogous to `select speaker, count(1) from line group by speaker`.  ("Line" is the type of document, and "speaker" is one of the properties.)

Now I have a query like this:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "query": {
      "match": {
        "play_name": "HAMLET"
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "line_count": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "speaker.speaker_raw"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The results look right, but the ElasticSearch docs specify that document counts for the terms aggregation are approximate (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html).  Is there some other magic to get exact counts within a bucket?

Separately, I already figured out that I had to pre-define a field on the index to have an un-analyzed version of "speaker" to ensure I can aggregate on the original field values, not tokenized.  (See [Elasticsearch - Cardinality over Full Field Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37337428/elasticsearch-cardinality-over-full-field-value))

Comment: Counts in ES are accurate and complete for `terms` aggregations, the only approximate values are (IIRC) for cardinality and percentiles aggregations. See: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html And: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-percentile-aggregation.html

Comment: docs for terms aggregation also say counts are approximate as well.   wondering if that is handled by size: 0?

Comment: Ha, never noticed that. If I'm reading correctly, the reason for the approximate count is due to shard bucketing being 'biased' regarding the 'top x' results. So I guess if you're using `size:0` it should be accurate, what do you think?

Comment: I think you're right about that.  If you make that an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-approximate-counts), the reason for the approximate count in the terms aggregation is due to shard bucketing being 'biased' regarding the 'top x' results.

If you set `"size": 0` I'm pretty certain that Elasticsearch will return accurate results.

Comment: Maybe changed in a recent version, but 0 causes an error `[size] must be greater than 0`

Answer (score 4):

Setting size:0 is now deprecated, due to memory issues inflicted on a cluster with high-cardinality field values. You can use only number between 1 to 2147483647.

Source: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/18838